# animate - как поменять background-color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте, скажите почему не получается изменить css свойство `background-color` при помощи `animate` в `JQuery`?

Код jquery:

```
$("#one").animate({"background-color":"red"}, 1000);
```

Код html:

```
<div style = "background-color: #FDFEC9; width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid green;">    
</div>
```

Такие свойства, как `height`, `width` меняет без проблем, а вот цвет заднего фона не может.

Comment: jquery.com:
>All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)

Comment: @KaZaца +1 - за умение пользоваться документацией :)

Answer (score 2):

[Color animation jQuery-plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) добавляем плагинчик весом в 2 Кб и получаем возможность анимировать цвета.

Comment: Также анимация цветов присутствует в jquery ui

Comment: Также анимация цветов присутствует в CSS3.